# Sort each character in a string from a specific column in Snowflake SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to alphabetically sort each value in a column with Snowflake. For example I have:

```
| NAME |
| ---- |
| abc |
| bca |
| acb |
```

and want

```
| NAME |
| ---- |
| abc |
| abc |
| abc |
```

how would I go about doing that? I've tried using SPLIT and the ordering the rows, but that doesn't seem to work without a specific delimiter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `REGEXP_REPLACE` to introduce separator between each character, `STRTOK_SPLIT_TO_TABLE` to get individual letters as rows and `LISTAGG` to combine again as sorted string:

```
SELECT tab.col, LISTAGG(s.value) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY s.value) AS result
FROM tab
, TABLE(STRTOK_SPLIT_TO_TABLE(REGEXP_REPLACE(tab.col, '(.)', '\\1~'), '~')) AS s
GROUP BY tab.col;
```

For sample data:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE tab
AS
SELECT 'abc' AS col UNION
SELECT 'bca' UNION
SELECT 'acb';
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Similar implementation as Lukasz's, but using `regexp_extract_all` to extract individual characters in the form of an array that we later split to rows using `flatten` . The `listagg` then stitches it back in the order we specify in `within group` clause.

```
with cte (col) as
(select 'abc' union
 select 'bca' union
 select 'acb')


select col, listagg(b.value) within group (order by b.value) as col2
from cte, lateral flatten(regexp_extract_all(col,'.')) b
group by col;
```